# How Does Peroxide + UV = Oxidation?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I restore shoes, & we have this method for oxidizing the translucent soles to get them to look new again.

The process is:
clean surface
Apply 40 Volume peroxide cream
Place under UV Growlight.

I follow the process. I get the results. But I don’t actually understand what happening. What does the peroxide & passing uv do to remove the yellowing? Can I concentrate the peroxide for more thorough & faster results? How big of a factor is the UV light? If I hade to make a compromise in either direction, would I be better off with more concentrated peroxide cream or more powerful UV source? I want to really understand what’s going on so that I can improve the service that I provide. Thank you for any time you put into this question.

[image]

Comment: You are not "de-oxidising" the shoes, you are oxidising them. The yellow colour comes from conjugated double bonds and oxidation destroys the double bonds and hence removes the colour. The oxidation is done by free oxygen radicals produced by photolysis of the peroxide molecules. This method is widely used by the retro computer enthusiast community, and is know as [retr0briting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retr0bright).

Comment: @JohnRennie Maybe convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @EdV There's way too much questions here.

Comment: @Mithoron You are probably right, if I understand your point, but some open questions attract very low quality answers, which would not be the case if the first commenter posts an answer. Just my opinion, anyway.

Comment: I appreciate that. I understand that there’s a lot of questions, but if you could help me with at least one, I’d be very grateful.

Comment: I do not consider myself qualified to answer the questions you have and @Mithoron put his finger on it: lots of questions. But there are many following questions: what is the polymeric translucent sole material?, what is 40 volume peroxide cream?, what is the wavelength range and intensity of the UV light?, how long does the treatment last?, and on and on. So you have a treatment method you feel works well, but it is empirical, as I see it, and I have no idea how you would improve it, given what I said, except by further trial and error experimentation. Sorry this is not so helpful.